# why my controller not wired with my repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("jerceka.workhard.demo")
@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo.Account")
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo")
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [Name=" + Name + ", Age=" + Age + "]";
    }
}
```

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;
@Repository
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{
    @Query("select * from Account where Name=?1")
    List<Account> findByName(String name);
}
```

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;
@Controller
public class Main{
    @Autowired
    Repo repo;
    @RequestMapping
    public String Home() {
        return "Home.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping("Create")
    public String Create(Account a) {
        repo.save(a);
        return "Home.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping("Bring")
    public ModelAndView Bring(@RequestParam int Id) {
        ModelAndView MV = new ModelAndView("Show.jsp");
//      Account a = repo.findById(Id).orElse(new Account());
//      System.out.println(repo.findByName("Mn"));
//      MV.addObject(a);
        return MV;
    }
}
```

give me that error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field repo in jerceka.workhard.demo.Main required a bean of type 'jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo' in your configuration.

Comment: Remove `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. The `@SpringBootApplication` will detect this.

Comment: didn't work and give me strange error *

Comment: Please add the error. The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is enough, as it is on a class in a toplevel, everything else (entities, repositories etc. will be automatically detected). The `@Query` isn't needed as well ,as that is infered from the `findByName` already. The same for `@Repository` that isn't needed on a Spring Data repository.

Comment: i make all what u ask, now give me this error(Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo.findByName(java.lang.String)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [name] on this ManagedType [jerceka.workhard.demo.Account]) i use mysql db btw

Comment: Your field is named `Name` where is should be `name`. Hence query creation fails and your repo cannot be found and thus wired. Fix your entity, in short use proper Java syntax.

Comment: can you show the project file structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with the framework however you are trying very hard to work around the framework with all annotations. Next your naming convention for the fields in your entities isn't according to what is expected and thus things start to break.

1. Remove all annotations from `TestApplication` except `@SpringBootApplication`
2. Remove `@Repository` and `@Query` from the `Repo`, also your key is an `Integer` not an `Long`.
3. In your entity follow proper naming conventions and use lowercase fields instead of uppercase, so `name` and `age` instead of `Name` and `Age`.

Your `TestApplication` should be something like this

```java
package jerceka.workhard.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

All the other things are automatically enabled.

Your `Repo` should be defined as follows, (I also renamed the method to `findAllByName` just because I think that matches better).

```java
package jerceka.workhard.demo;

public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer>{

    List<Account> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

Finally your entity should follow proper naming conventions.

```java
package jerceka.workhard.demo;

@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [Name=" + this.anme + ", Age=" + this.age + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 ) SpringBootApplication is a self sufficient annotation**

You don't actually need all your annotations in your class *TestApplication*.
Just keep `@SpringBootApplication` like following:

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**2) Respect the naming conventions of attributes**

In your class *Account*, your attributes begin with an uppercase letter. You should respect this simple naming convention. It will be easier to read for someone who don't know your code:

- Begins with a lowercase letter
- Use an uppercase letter to seperate the words in your attribute (example: myAttribute)

**3) Remove @Query in your Repository**

You don't actually need this annotation because the method below is respecting the query method naming convention, so your request will exactly be the same. You can find more about this macanism [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).
Your repository should look like this:

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;

@Repository
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{

    List<Account> findByName(String name);
}
```

**4) You shouldn't inject your Repository directly in your Controller**

The repository should only be used to communicate with the database. It shouldn't be directly injected in the Controller. If you want to have a clean code (in my opinion), you should create a Service (annotated with *@Service*), and write all your logic in this class. The Service class is the heart of your application.

**5) Use @GetMapping, @PostMapping, etc... instead of @RequestMapping**

Request mapping is the "base" annotation and it's not forbidden to use it. But since there are newest annotations, you should use them. `@GetMapping` is exactly the same as `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`, but more readable.

**6) Respect the REST naming convention for the mapping urls**

You should wirte your path following this simple rules:

- Begin your path with "/"
- Only use lowercase
- separate the words with a "-"

  In your case, your URL should look like this: 
  *"/create"*, *"/bring"*

  *I hope this will help you, and your code will works. You still can ask me questions in comment section.*

Comment: thanks a lot for all that instructions really help me a lot your answer i will follow those rules and service will add soon and GetMapping and PostMapping will use it :) ,thanks for  all that

Answer (score 0):

Change the Repo code as:

```
package jerceka.workhard.demo;
@Repository
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer>{
    @Query("select * from Account where Name=?1")
    List<Account> findByName(String name);
}
```

The data type of id is int in entity but you are using Long in the repository.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i try that now and didn't work, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change this line above your class `TestApplication`:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo")
```

It should be this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo")
```

The annotation takes a package name, not the name of a class or interface.

Comment: thanks for your time but that give me another error`Error creating bean with name 'repo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class jerceka.workhard.demo.Account`

Comment: @Jerceka That's because you made the same mistake in this line: `@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo.Account")` should be `@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo")`

Comment: this is my main class`SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("jerceka.workhard.demo")
@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo")
public class TestApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
 }

}
` not working and give me * error

Answer (score 0):

remove `Repo` class name or replace following code

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo")
```

Comment: thanks for your time but that give me another error`Error creating bean with name 'repo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class jerceka.workhard.demo.Account`

Answer (score 0):

In `TestApplication` you should kept only `SpringBootApplication`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And change select in `Repo`

```java
@Repository
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    @Query("select a from Account a where a.name=?1")
    List<Account> findByName(String name);
}
```

And change you id to `Long` in `Account`

Answer (score 0):

`@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` take an array of **basePackages** for scanning.

So instead of

```
@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo.Account")
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo.Repo")
```

Use:

```
@EntityScan("jerceka.workhard.demo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("jerceka.workhard.demo")
```

Note: But since you have `@SpringBootApplication` in root level of package `"jerceka.workhard.demo"` already so you just need `@SpringBootApplication`